# After applying security update 2015-04 on Mavericks some site SSL certificates fail

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I applied security update 2015-04 on Mavericks and afterwards some site SSL certificates (e.g. Twitter, support.apple.com, etc) fail.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Related: http://whatquestions.com/using-mac-app-store/85616-app-store-unavailable-following-security-update-2015-004-Mavericks

Comment: That link looks like it might be related, but it's just someone else with a similar problem.  I didn't see any solutions, so I'm not sure how it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Solution from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6984765?searchText=2015-004 :

> I solved this problem by deleting all VeriSign certificates in my login keychain.
>
> I did not touch any certificates in the System Roots keychain.
>
> I exported the 4 certs there first of course, but App Store and iTunes connected and work properly without them in my login keychain.